# How to apply for a Thai visa with a US travel document issued to refugees?

Tags: visas, thailand

I'm applying for a visa for Thailand with a US Travel Document I-327 (I'm a Permanent US Resident). Should I put "STATELESS" in the nationality box? My nationality says Stateless on my Travel Document. I'm not sure if I should put down what's on my document or what my actual nationality is (where I was born).

Comment: I would match my application to the travel document. Is there another space to put place of birth?

Comment: Well, are you stateless (i.e. you have no country's nationality)? You don't necessarily have the nationality of the country where you were born -- you have a country's nationality if and only if that country's laws say you do. You being a US permanent resident and holding a US Re-entry Permit (which any permanent resident can get) do not mean you are stateless. Your Re-entry Permit says "stateless" probably because that's what you put for your nationality on the application form; but is it right?

Comment: Thank you, you just answered my question. Yes there is a (Nationality) (Birthplace) and (Nationality at birth option). And no i didn’t personally put Stateless, i had no idea that was a thing. It was about a 6 month process of me describing my situation until They figured out i’m Statless because my family in a sense ran from Communism, and i guess that’s how it happens. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Your current nationality is stateless, so that is what you would put there.

Your nationality at birth would be of the country you were born in that no longer exists as it was before the breakup of the Soviet Union.